# Can't read StandardOutput when calling wkhtmltopdf with a ProcessInfo UserName and Password

Tags: c#, .net, process, console, wkhtmltopdf

I've used wkhtmltopdf successfully before but now I have a scenario were I need to use a specific account when starting the process. When I set a valid username/pwd the standardoutput stream is empty and the return code is -1. As soon as I comment out the username/pwd it works as expected.

Testing this in .Net 4, Win 7 64 bit.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wkhtmlDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var wkhtml = wkhtmlDir + @"\wkhtmltopdf.exe";

        var info = new ProcessStartInfo(wkhtml);

        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlDir;

        info.Arguments = "http://www.google.com -";

        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        var password = "mypassword";

        foreach (var c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        //comment out next three lines, and it works!
        info.UserName = "myuser"; 
        info.Password = securePassword;
        info.Domain = "mydomain"; 

        using (var process = Process.Start(info))
        {
            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            // wait or exit
            process.WaitForExit(60000);

            var returnCode = process.ExitCode;
        }

    }
```

If I comment out the info.UserName, Password, Domain, output has data, otherwise if I try using credentials, output is blank and the returnCode is -1.

Hoping others have run into this, seems like a common scenario, am sure missing something simple...

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using WKHTMLTOPDF in a .net application.  A couple of things I've discovered which may help you are:

- The output from the wkhtmltopdf process gets put into StandardError, not StandardOutput.  So you should redirect the StandardError stream NOT StandardOutput
- Redirecting BOTH standardError and StandardOutput as you have done will potentially (and in my experience of wkhtmltopdf always) cause a deadlock in your application.  See this page for more information on why http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

In your case you may be having issues with an error being written and causing a deadlock?

You can set your process to asynchronously read both standarderror and standard output as I have done in my example below . I hope this helps

```
sub doConversion()
        dim p as System.Diagnostics.Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "wkhtmltopdf.exe"

        dim url as string = "[[[YOUR URL TO CONVERT]]]"
        dim outfilename as string = "[[[WHERE YOU WANT THE FILE]]]"
        dim switches as string = ""
        switches &= "--disable-smart-shrinking  --print-media-type "
        switches &= "--margin-top 0mm --margin-bottom 0mm --margin-right 0mm --margin-left 0mm "
        switches &= "--page-size A4 "

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = switches & Url & " " & outfilename

        console.writeline("Running command: " & commandToRun & " " & switches & Url & " " & outfilename)

        '## needs to be false in order to redirect output
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false 

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true
        AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, addressOf PDFOutputHandler

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true
        AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, addressOf PDFOutputHandler

        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = rootPath & iif(rootpath.endswith("\"),"","\") 
        console.writeline("Starting...")

        try
            p.Start()
            p.BeginOutputReadLine()
            p.BeginErrorReadLine()
            console.writeline("Started...")
        catch ex as exception
            throw new exception("Could not start process [" & p.startInfo.Filename & "] with arguments [" & p.startInfo.Arguments & "], " & vbcrlf & "(RootPath: " & rootpath & ")" & vbcrlf & ex.tostring & vbcrlf)
        end try

        '## ...then wait for exit 
        p.WaitForExit()
end sub

Private Sub PDFOutputHandler(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
        console.writeline(outLine.Data)
     End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, is it possible in .net, but when I create processes with different credentials (e.g. CreateProcessAsUser in Win API) and create a pipe, I must obviously pass to CreateNamedPipe [Null security or Local security](http://conemu-maximus5.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ConEmu/src/common/MSecurity.cpp) attributes.

May be you have the same problem.